# C# Metro app toast notifications show up after long delay or not at all on Local Machine?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, toast

I have a Windows Store App (Metro) that uses toast notifications.  The notifications work beautifully when remote debugging on my WinRT device (Surface 2). However, when running on my desktop in Local Machine or Simulator mode, they are *really* erratic.  Sometimes showing up several minutes later and occasionally not at all.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't have control over that. That's one of the reasons they tell you not to use toast for critical information, as it's not guaranteed to deliver.